# Animation doesn't update

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to redo this Qt code https://github.com/laserpants/qt-material-widgets but using Python & PyQt4 and I'm encountering problem with animation.

I want to recreate the checkbox of the example, everything is working fine except the animation; it doesn't update.

The main issue is that I want to keep the stateMachine and the transitions for the button, but the solutions I found does not use them.

I just want the icon to fade-in & out when clicked

any Idea why this is not working?

```py
class materialCheckBox(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(materialCheckBox,self).__init__(parent)

        self.setProperty("value", bool)

        checkedIcon = materialIcon(self, "C:/Users/User/.qgis2/python/plugins/Material/icons/baseline-check_box-24px.svg")
        uncheckedIcon = materialIcon(self, "C:/Users/User/.qgis2/python/plugins/Material/icons/baseline-check_box_outline_blank-24px.svg")

        self.stateMachine = QStateMachine()

        self.checkedState = QState()
        self.checkedState.assignProperty(self, "value", True)
        self.checkedState.assignProperty(checkedIcon, "opacity", 1.0)
        self.checkedState.assignProperty(uncheckedIcon, "opacity", 0.0)

        self.uncheckedState = QState()
        self.uncheckedState.assignProperty(self, "value", False)
        self.uncheckedState.assignProperty(checkedIcon, "opacity", 0.0)
        self.uncheckedState.assignProperty(uncheckedIcon, "opacity", 1.0)

        self.stateMachine.addState(self.checkedState)
        self.stateMachine.addState(self.uncheckedState)
        self.stateMachine.setInitialState(self.uncheckedState)

        transition1 = self.checkedState.addTransition(self.clicked, self.uncheckedState)
        animation1 = QPropertyAnimation(checkedIcon, "opacity", self)
        animation1.setDuration(2000)
        transition1.addAnimation(animation1)
        animation2 = QPropertyAnimation(uncheckedIcon, "opacity", self)
        animation2.setDuration(2000)
        transition1.addAnimation(animation2)

        transition2 = self.uncheckedState.addTransition(self.clicked, self.checkedState)
        animation3 = QPropertyAnimation(checkedIcon, "opacity", self)
        animation3.setDuration(2000)
        transition2.addAnimation(animation3)
        animation4 = QPropertyAnimation(uncheckedIcon, "opacity", self)
        animation4.setDuration(2000)
        transition2.addAnimation(animation4)

        self.stateMachine.start()

        self.clicked.connect(self.update)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 24, 24)

    def isChecked(self):
        return self.property("value")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class materialIcon(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, address):
        super(materialIcon, self).__init__(parent)
        self.icon = QPixmap(address)
        self.setProperty("opacity", float)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setOpacity(self.property("opacity"))

        mask = QPainter(self.icon)
        mask.begin(self.icon)
        mask.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_SourceIn)
        mask.fillRect(self.icon.rect(), QColor(0, 158, 227))
        mask.end()

        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.icon)
        painter.end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the update() method every time the opacity changes, so it's better to create a pyqtProperty than a dynamic property:

```py
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
icons_path = file = os.path.join(root_path, "icons")


class MaterialCheckBox(QtGui.QWidget):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    toggled = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MaterialCheckBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self._is_checked = False

        checkedIcon = MaterialIcon(
            self, os.path.join(icons_path, "baseline-check_box-24px.svg")
        )
        uncheckedIcon = MaterialIcon(
            self,
            os.path.join(
                icons_path, "baseline-check_box_outline_blank-24px.svg"
            ),
        )

        stateMachine = QtCore.QStateMachine(self)

        checkedState = QtCore.QState()
        checkedState.assignProperty(self, b"checked", True)
        checkedState.assignProperty(checkedIcon, b"opacity", 1.0)
        checkedState.assignProperty(uncheckedIcon, b"opacity", 0.0)

        uncheckedState = QtCore.QState()
        uncheckedState.assignProperty(self, b"checked", False)
        uncheckedState.assignProperty(checkedIcon, b"opacity", 0.0)
        uncheckedState.assignProperty(uncheckedIcon, b"opacity", 1.0)

        stateMachine.addState(checkedState)
        stateMachine.addState(uncheckedState)
        stateMachine.setInitialState(uncheckedState)

        duration = 2000

        transition1 = checkedState.addTransition(self.clicked, uncheckedState)
        animation1 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            checkedIcon, b"opacity", self, duration=duration
        )
        transition1.addAnimation(animation1)
        animation2 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            uncheckedIcon, b"opacity", self, duration=duration
        )
        transition1.addAnimation(animation2)

        transition2 = uncheckedState.addTransition(self.clicked, checkedState)
        animation3 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            checkedIcon, b"opacity", self, duration=duration
        )
        transition2.addAnimation(animation3)
        animation4 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            uncheckedIcon, b"opacity", self, duration=duration
        )
        transition2.addAnimation(animation4)

        stateMachine.start()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(24, 24)

    def isChecked(self):
        return self._is_checked

    def setChecked(self, value):
        if self._is_checked != value:
            self._is_checked = value
            self.toggled.emit(self._is_checked)

    checked = QtCore.pyqtProperty(
        bool, fget=isChecked, fset=setChecked, notify=toggled
    )

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
        self.update()
        super(MaterialCheckBox, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class MaterialIcon(QtGui.QWidget):
    opacityChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent, address):
        super(MaterialIcon, self).__init__(parent)
        self.icon = QtGui.QPixmap(address)
        self._opacity = 0.0

    def opacity(self):
        return self._opacity

    def setOpacity(self, o):
        if o != self._opacity:
            self._opacity = o
            self.opacityChanged.emit()
            self.update()

    opacity = QtCore.pyqtProperty(
        float, fget=opacity, fset=setOpacity, notify=opacityChanged
    )

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setOpacity(self.opacity)
        mask = QtGui.QPainter(self.icon)
        mask.setCompositionMode(QtGui.QPainter.CompositionMode_SourceIn)
        mask.fillRect(self.icon.rect(), QtGui.QColor(0, 158, 227))
        mask.end()
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.icon)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MaterialCheckBox()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The complete example is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/blob/master/questions/55707726/main.py).